# Create folder when installing composer package

Tags: composer-php

Is it possible for a composer package to create a folder (or folders) in the root directory of the project?

For example:

```
/ansible
/application
/public
/composer.json
/composer.lock
```

I run `composer install` to install my package (framework).
Can this framework create the folders `/logs` in my root directory?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md and check the `post-install-cmd` event name and supply your own script to create your needed directories.